# Calculating the influence of a user in a telecom cdr data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I came across a way to calculate the influence score of a person on a twitter network. Here is a sample reference: http://thenoisychannel.com/2009/01/13/a-twitter-analog-to-pagerank/

On similar lines, are there any other algorithms that calculate the influence score of a subscriber on a telecom network using his/her CDR data?

Comment: I think this question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications, if you like the idea, ask your question there and follow the proposal

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout Magnusson's thesis:
http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2:509757

This thesis aims at investigating the usefulness of social network analysis in telecommunication networks. As these networks can be very large the methods used to study them must scale linearly when the network size increases. Thus, an integral part of the study is to determine which social network analysis algorithms that have this scalability. Moreover, comparisons of software solutions are performed to find product suitable for these specific tasks.